Setting Facebook pixel cookie _fbp cookie domain
when using a Facebook pixel script on your website it generates a _fbp cookie. Default this cookie is set on TLD and not on hostname. This is causing issues with subdomains, therefore I want to set the cookie on hostname.
I found this meta information on _fbp parameters which has a subdomainIndex parameter which, when set to two, will set the cookie on hostname: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/conversions-api/parameters/fbp-and-fbc#fbp
However, I cannot find how I feed this parameter to the default meta pixel script. Any pointers are appreciated!
<script>
  !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s)
  {if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
  n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};
  if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';
  n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
  t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window, document,'script',
  'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
  fbq('init', '{your-pixel-id-goes-here}');
  fbq('track', 'PageView');
</script>
<noscript>
  <img height="1" width="1" style="display:none" 
       src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id={your-pixel-id-goes-here}&ev=PageView&noscript=1"/>
</noscript>
<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->```


AFAIK this isn't something you can specify when embedding the script. At most you can try and make use of how it behaves, as explained there on that page you linked to: _"the Pixel automatically saves a unique identifier to an fbp cookie for the website domain if one does not already exist." - so if you try and set such a cookie yourself when it not already exists, before the pixel script initializes, it might work ...

But if there isn't a way to set the cookie domain, how does subdomainIndex get determined by meta? They have 3 possible values 0 (.com), 1 (domain.com) and 2 (sub.domain.com).
If I start with a clean browser, go to sub.domain.com, accept cookies en refresh I still get subdomainIndex 1, so on TLD and not on hostname. It is not set based on what is in the address bar of the browser

I'm guessing this is rather a problem of how you configured your pixel. How did you set it up, which domain(s) did you add?

you can only add TLD's in the pixel setup for www.domain.com. If you add www.domain.com, meta changes this in the 'allowed' list to domain.com

And tried the other way around, the exclude list. Meta says it won't sent data from websites on the exclude list, but the cookie is still present on those websites.
Don't think the data authority accepts this.

So the "issue" on the subdomains is not of a technical nature then, but regarding data protection/privacy? Have you tried setting an initial cookie with the subdomainIndex set to 2 yourself?

No, if I have to go to all that trouble (you need to make a connection to the meta SDK to get the unique pixel number. So this requires code, which in our environment with multiple scrum teams is a lot of work to setup), we'll just choose to not use Facebook pixel
